# Alternar entre resultados

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Olá!

Tenho as seguintes consultas:

```
SELECT id,
       nome,
       idade,
       data_nascimento,
       cpf
 FROM internos
 WHERE cpf = '12345678911'
```

e

```
SELECT id,
       nome,
       idade,
       data_nascimento,
       cpf
 FROM externos
 WHERE cpf = '12345678911'
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para alternar entre os resultados:

Como assim?

Caso a data de nascimento do resultado da consulta de cima viesse nula, trouxesse o da consulta de baixo, da linha toda:

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
SELECT id,
           nome,
           idade,
           IFNULL(data_nascimento, A.data_nascimento),
           cpf
     FROM internos
     WHERE cpf = '12345678911'

    UNION
   (
    SELECT id,
           nome,
           idade,
           data_nascimento,
           cpf
     FROM externos
     WHERE cpf = '12345678911'
 ) A
```

Porque as vezes não dados tem em uma tabela mas, tem em outra

A princípio o resultado vem assim:

```
 ____________________________________________________________
[ id  |  nome   |  idade  |   data_nascimento  |  cpf        ]  
[ 1   |  Carlos |   NULL  |     NULL           | 12345678911 ]
[ 15  |  carlos |   20    |     1999-04-01     | 12345678911 ]
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Na consulta eu gostaria que prevalecesse a consulta de baixo

```
 ____________________________________________________________
[ id  |  nome   |  idade  |   data_nascimento  |  cpf        ]  
[ 15  |  carlos |   20    |     1999-04-01     | 12345678911 ]
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[EDIT]**

Caso tenha os dados completos no primeiro resultado, o segundo estará vazio

Comment: Se não estiver null nas 2 tabelas o que você deseja fazer ?

Comment: Na verdade, se tiver completo na primeira, não tem na segunda

Comment: Para quê fazer isso em SQL?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que no segundo select não vai existir caso esteja completo na primeira, outra forma de você fazer seria adicionando no where do select is not null.

```
SELECT id,
       nome,
       idade,
       data_nascimento,
       cpf
FROM internos
WHERE cpf = '12345678911'
  AND data_nascimento IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT id,
       nome,
       idade,
       data_nascimento,
       cpf
FROM externos
WHERE cpf = '12345678911'
  AND data_nascimento IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Só que assim se tiver resultados nos 2 irão aparecer duas linhas.

Comment: Mas é o que o usuário quer, apenas 1 linha, e conforme ele mencionou, se estiver completo na primeira não terá na segunda.

Comment: Realmente veio conforme o desejado

Answer (score 2):

Pela explicação do retorno esperado, seria mais indicado você usar um [`right join`](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-left-e-right-join-consultar-dados-em-duas-ou-mais-tabelas-30/) ao invés do `union`, já que pretende trazer prioritariamente o que tem na segunda tabela:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.nome, e.idade, e.data_nascimento, e.cpf
FROM internos i
RIGHT JOIN externos e ON e.cpf = i.cpf
WHERE e.cpf = '12345678911'
```

Considerando que os dados retornados serão iguais nas duas tabelas, o `distinct` filtrará para que seja selecionada apenas uma ocorrência (quando tiver o mesmo usuário nas duas).

DETALHE: o `id` das tabelas são independentes entre si, então para que o *distinct* funcione exatamente como falei, removi do retorno.

---

Pelo comentário do @adventistaam, pode tentar usando apenas o `join`, validando qual data exibir:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   IF(e.data_nascimento is null, i.nome, e.nome) as nome, 
   IF(e.data_nascimento is null, i.idade, e.idade) as idade, 
   IF(e.data_nascimento is null, i.data_nascimento, e.data_nascimento) as data_nascimento,
   IF(e.data_nascimento is null, i.cpf, e.cpf) as cpf
FROM internos i
JOIN externos e ON e.cpf = i.cpf
WHERE e.cpf = '12345678911'
```

Comment: Nesse caso, o RIGHT deixou nulo outros campos e usando LEFT vieram as mesmas informações

Comment: No caso do `IFNULL` não funcionaria, apenas o `IF`, então seria `IF(var IS NULL, val1, val2)`

Comment: isso.. copiei o `ifnull` e alterei dentro por causa dos outros campos.. esqueci de mudar ele msm xD vou corrigir.. mas resolve?

Comment: Resolve sim, Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se a data de nascimento é nula e considere a tabela adequada.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN i.data_nascimento IS NULL THEN e.id ELSE i.id END AS id, 
    CASE WHEN i.data_nascimento IS NULL THEN e.nome ELSE i.nome END AS nome,
    CASE WHEN i.data_nascimento IS NULL THEN e.idade ELSE i.idade END AS idade,
    CASE WHEN i.data_nascimento IS NULL THEN e.cpf ELSE i.cpf END AS cpf
FROM internos i RIGHT JOIN externos e ON (i.cpf = e.cpf)
WHERE e.cpf = '12345678911';
```

Comment: Nesse caso o `if` não resolveria?

Comment: Sim para o MySQL poderia ser: IF (i.data_nascimento IS NULL, e.id, i.id) AS id.